# Сделать кнопку и input на всю ширину контейнера

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня у `input'a` и у `button'a` задан:

```
width: 100%;
```

но почему то `button` меньше чем `input`:

[image: photo]

Comment: так откройте инспектор в инструментах браузера и посмотрите, мб margin у кнопки справа есть

Comment: @teran что?я просто новичок.

Comment: В браузере на странице которую разрабатываете нажмите кнопочку F12 и нажмите на квадратик внутри которого есть курсор! Или же cCTRL+SHIFT+C. Наведите на элемент и нажмите на него и Вы увидите все размеры, стили и т.д. Почитать можно здесь:
[тыц](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/ru/use-google-chrome-web-inspector.html)

Comment: @DenysSkotarenko ну я узнал что размер кнопки меньше размера input-a на 40px,но что дальше ?

Comment: @fen1x не мешало бы код в студию завести

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У таких "сложных" элементов как `input` и `button` стоит обнулять дефолтные стили перед тем как приступать к дизайну, это поможет избежать "неожиданностей" впоследствии:

```css
input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font: inherit;
  letter-spacing: unset;
  word-spacing: unset;
  line-height: 1;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: unset;
  writing-mode: unset;
  text-rendering: unset;
  text-indent: 0;
  color: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: unset;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: default;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: unset;
  font: inherit;
  font-variant-caps: unset;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant-ligatures: unset;
  font-variant-numeric: unset;
  font-variant-east-asian: unset;
  font-stretch: unset;
  letter-spacing: unset;
  word-spacing: unset;
  line-height: 1;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: unset;
  writing-mode: unset;
  text-rendering: unset;
  text-indent: 0;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: unset;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Например: Москва, Россия" />
<button>Узнать погоду</button>
```

*Если Вы не используете решения типа Autoprefixer, то стоит так же добавить вендорные префиксы для свойств которым это необходимо.*

Comment: хорошо.спасибо,я понял свою ошибку